# How do I mock the user in a Spring controller, and debug when something's missing or not mocked?

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC application (4.2.1) with a controller that requires "ADMIN" privileges. I'm trying to test that normal users get a "403", and admins get a "200". It works in the browser, but in my unit tests, both tests fail with a "302" status returned.

I believe that I've set everything up by the book to use `@WithMockUser`. I'd like to know how to figure out WHY I'm getting a 302 status. I suspect it's redirecting to the login page because it's not showing the user as logged in at all, but how do I verify that?

```
@Test
@WithMockUser(roles={"USER","ADMIN"})
public void requestProtectedUrlWithAdminRole() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(get("/admin/").with(csrf()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Admin")))
        .andReturn();
}
```

UPDATE:

I discovered that I can print the request and response by adding `.andDo(print())` between the `perform` method call and the first `.andExpect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(adding my comment as an answer) I reckon that you're missing a Listener and that's why the annotation is not being used. Add the following annotation to your test class

```
@TestExecutionListeners( { WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener.class })
```

You might need other listeners, for other features, but you definitely need that one to make the annotation `@WithMockUser` work fine.

The debugging part is tricky... you can start put some breakpoints on DispatcherServlet, or in the filter that checks the user (I'm sorry, but I don't know which class does the authentication/authorisation).

Comment: That was the missing piece I needed. Thank you!